# Add new Item to a List if search result is empty (UISearchBar)

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a `UITableView` with items. A user can add an item by opening another `UITableView` in which they find a `UISearchBar`/`UISearchDisplayController` with a big Glossary of items. If they can't find a word ("No Results") it should be able to add the text that was typed into the searchfield directly into the main `UITableView` list.

The easiest way seems to change the name "Search" into "Add Item" and listen to `searchBarSearchButtonClicked`. But without editing subviews etc. this is not possible.

Is there a workaround for it?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this issue? How would you have to edit the subviews? Would be good to add this piece of code/info to the question.

Comment: No, I did not find a proper solution for it. I was afraid to edit subviews since perhaps in an iOS update the code is not relevant anymore. That's why I did not look any further. The state is, that the user has to press "Cancel" and has to press another button to enter a new item.